# System.IO.IOException: The handshake failed due to an unexpected > packet format?

Tags: c#, wcf

Does anyone know what this means?

> System.Net.WebException: The
>   underlying connection was closed: An
>   unexpected error occurred on a send.
>   ---> System.IO.IOException: The handshake failed due to an unexpected
>   packet format. at
>   System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[]
>   buffer, Int32 readBytes,
>   AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) at
>   System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[]
>   buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest
>   asyncRequest) at
>   System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken
>   message, AsyncProtocolRequest
>   asyncRequest) at
>   System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[]
>   incoming, Int32 count,
>   AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) at
>   System.Net.Security.SslState.ForceAuthentication(Boolean
>   receiveFirst, Byte[] buffer,
>   AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest) at
>   System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult
>   lazyResult) at
>   System.Net.TlsStream.CallProcessAuthentication(Object
>   state) at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(Object
>   userData) at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode
>   code, CleanupCode backoutCode, Object
>   userData) at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback
>   callback, Object state) at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback
>   callback, Object state) at
>   System.Net.TlsStream.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult
>   result) at
>   System.Net.TlsStream.Write(Byte[]
>   buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size) at
>   System.Net.PooledStream.Write(Byte[]
>   buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size) at
>   System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeaders(Boolean
>   async) --- End of inner exception
>   stack trace --- at
>   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
>   at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan
>   timeout) at

**EDIT:**

This is the method I was calling:

> _productsService = new ProductsPortTypeClient();
>   _productsService.GetResortProducts(GetProductsCredentials(),
>                           GetResortProductParams());

Comment: What were you doing when you got the exception? And perhaps you could post the full stack trace?

Comment: Just a routine webservice - see edit

Comment: Is this webservice configured for NTLM/Kerberoes authentication?

Comment: Perhaps the service definition has changed and you need to refresh your reference to it?

Comment: @sajoshi - I don't know what that is.

Comment: If you are using WCF Service, try running WCFTestClient from .NET command prompt and see if adds the reference..

Comment: This problem could happen if you mixed up http and https in your uri. It's an easy mistake to make (and fix)!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It looks like a problem with SSL authentication, it fails at handshake phase, maybe two implementations are not compatible, you may check the WSDL format of the response, figure out what format should be used for communication and check if the one sent by you complies with it (you may use any kind of a network monitor software, eg. Microsoft Network Monitor)

Answer (score 10):

I just wanted to make an answer based on one of the comments because it can cause this error to happen.

In some cases, if you have a `BaseURL` while  calling a `API`, then the problem could happen if you mixed up `http` and `https`. This happened in my case while calling a Google `API`. This is a simple fix in some cases and can happen to anyone.

Hope this help's someone out.

Comment: In short, trying to access an HTTP endpoint via HTTPS will give you this error message.

Comment: seven blessings for pointing out my stupidity

Answer (score 7):

In my case it was Skype blocking 443 port. Go to Skype tools-advanced-connections and disable "Use port 80 & 443 for connections..."

Comment: Ugh, that is some irritating Skype behavior.  I can't count the number of times I've had to use Skype for a conference call and forgot I left it running, then started to tear my hair out why the web server application I was working on wouldn't start up.

Answer (score 4):

**summary: wrong port was used.**

My service was running in development on port :58328 but next time I debugged it was running on port :44315, and this caused the issue. 
So changing the port on the client side to 44315 helped to resolve the issue!